# Telegram bot - Remove keyboard - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm facing a very strange issue that is probably linked to cache.

So here it is .
I have developped a bot in nodejs for telegram.

This bot HAD in the past a custom keyboard that was not a "inline_keyboard"
I decided to change that behaviour and have implemented inline_keyboard.

current code is something like that :

```
  var options = {
    parse_mode: "Markdown",
    disable_web_page_preview: true,
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
      inline_keyboard: [
        [{
          text: ' English',
          callback_data: "SET ENGLISH"
        },{
          text: ' Français',
          callback_data: "SET FRENCH"
        }]
      ]
    })
  };

  bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, "Please choose your language",options);
```

Inline_keyboard is working fine but my old code (that has been deleted) is still appearing to my users and is very anoying.

Here it is; it keeps on appearing when my users log into my chat.
[image: anoying keyboard]

I have been the following ressources :

- https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardremove
- [How do you remove reply keyboard without sending a message in Telegram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120494/how-do-you-remove-reply-keyboard-without-sending-a-message-in-telegram)
- https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagereplymarkup

But i don't see how to implement it so I can remove this annoying chat for my users.

Any suggestions ? 
Thx for your support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there may be different solutions to do so, my suggestion:

you can use the very first answer of each user to remove keyboard, first use editMessageText to remove keyboard and then send him the appropriate answer.(note that persist chatIDs that you have removed their keyboard, so you will do this for each user just once)

```
bot.on('callback_query', function onCallbackQuery(callbackQuery) {
    if(!didWeRemoveHisKeyboard(callbackQuery.from.id))
        removeHisKeyboard(callbackQuery)
    //then handle the user response
})

removeHisKeyboard = function(callbackQuery){
    bot.editMessageText(callbackQuery.message.text,
    {message_id:callbackQuery.message.message_id , chat_id:callbackQuery.from.id,
    reply_markup: {
        remove_keyboard: true
    }}).catch((err) => {
        //some error handling
    }).then(function(res){
         if(res)
             addThisChatToHandledList(callbackQuery.from.id)
    })

}
```

note that you may need some modification on this code based on the node_module you're using.

Comment: thx for your reply. I'll test it and upvote it if it helps me !

Comment: For me the really important point in this answer is the `remove_keyboard: true` line. Without it the keyboard persists for every message.